# Deterministic generation of RSA encryption key pairs

Tags: java, android, rsa

I am trying to deterministically generate an RSA key pair using Java on Android.  My requirements are such that I can't store the key pair and it must be generated at run time to be equivalent to any previous/future runs.

My though process was that I would deterministically seed a random number generator and pass that generator along to create the keys.  My code is:

```
SecureRandom random=SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
random.setSeed(1234);   //something device specific will be used to set this
KeyPairGenerator keyGen=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

KeyPair pair=keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pub=pair.getPublic();
PrivateKey priv=pair.getPrivate();
```

The resulting keys are different from run to run.  However, the SecureRandom numbers are the same from run to run and even the same across devices.

What am I missing?  How can I can I repeatably generate these keys?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Surely if you're not wanting to store the RSA key pair, then you also wouldn't want to be storing the random seed used to generate the RSA pair? It is strange that this code isn't doing what you want it to, but to me it seems like you might be doing this without having thought it through

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Even if this works, this code would rely on a quirk of the SHA1PRNG implementation on Android, so it might break at any time. Generally, `setSeed()` adds entropy so you can't guarantee that you will get the same numbers even if you seed the `SecureRandom` with the same seed. If you try this code on desktop Java it will most probably fail. So far it works on most (all?) current Android versions, but this is not guaranteed.

If you want predictable keys, you might need to provision each device with pre-generated keys. If you need to store them securely, use the `KeyChain` API on ICS, or a pass-phrase protected keystore on pre-ICS devices. Even if you don't store the actual key, if someone knows how the keys are generated (the seed), they could generate the same keys, and your keys are only as secure as the seed. If it is device specific, chances are it's not too hard to find.

As for why this doesn't work, the RSA key generator basically generates random `BigIntegers` in a loop, testing for primes. The prime test is probabilistic, so you might get different primes chosen on each run. You might want to get [SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle), run this on an emulator and set breakpoints in `RSAKeyPairGenerator.java` to check what exactly is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on how the key generator works and the SpongyCastle implementation.  This is all part of a (misguided) attempt to minimize piracy of content from in-app purchases.  My hope was that I could encrypt the content on the server and deliver it to the client without a key exchange, and decrypt the content on the fly.  I'll have to generate the key pair on the server, transmit the private key to the client, and then use the KeyStore, as you suggested, with some algorithmically generated password to increase the difficultly a bit.

Comment: I see (kind of). You are trying to implement a DRM of sorts. RSA might not be best for this. If you transmit the key to the client, you naturally need to make sure this happens securely, and this might not be easy. On idea is to put some device specific bit (IMEI, etc.) in the IAB developerPayload and get it when you verify the signature on your server. Then use this to generate a symmetric (AES) key, bound to that particular device, encrypt the content and send it to the device. The device then generates the same symmetric key, and decrypts the content.

Comment: Of course you might want to hash the IMEI, etc. so that you don't collect actual device identifying information.

Comment: Excellent point on using AES, it should be easy to derive the same key from the same hash using PBKDF or similar.  Thanks again.

Comment: Deterministic generation of keypair helps us to store the seed and generate the wallet keys every time.